# How to group a stacked bar plot into 3 different columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, facet-wrap

I have a dataset ("data_for_plot.csv") that looks like the below

```
Sample,Cyanobacteria,Rhodophyta,Unknown_phylum,Chlorophyta,Bacillariophyta,Cercozoa,Apicomplexa,Unclassified,Streptophyta,species
S047424,18.8176,10.2027,21.6216,28.8514,0,16.3851,0,4.12162,0,SpeciesName1
S047423,26.3215,22.8883,17.4932,22.8883,1.3624,5.61308,0,3.43324,0,SpeciesName1
S047422,41.305,1.91199,14.5372,39.5751,0,0.971168,0,1.69954,0,SpeciesName1
S047420,98.2477,0,1.75232,0,0,0,0,0,0,SpeciesName2
S047419,19.6175,0,42.3893,37.9932,0,0,0,0,0,SpeciesName2
S047418,45.9008,0,0,0,0,54.0992,0,0,0,SpeciesName2
S047417,0.801603,8.01603,67.4349,3.00601,19.2385,1.50301,0,0,0,SpeciesName2
S047404,10.0267,58.2888,23.262,2.31729,2.94118,3.16399,0,0,0,SpeciesName3
S047402,1.67364,70.9044,11.2649,0,11.0074,0,0,5.14966,0,SpeciesName3
S047400,25.9087,27.959,31.8733,0,9.13327,5.12582,0,0,0,SpeciesName3
```

and I need to build a stacked bar plot that is split by the species column. There are 3 different species and so stacked bar plots should appear in 3 different columns with the corresponding species label (SpeciesName1/2/3) appearing without underscores. I tried the below code but I got the error message `At least one layer must contain all faceting variables:species`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
pc = read.csv("data_for_plot.csv", header = TRUE)
# The below replaces all single underscores with a single space in the taxon names on the final plot 
pc <- pc %>% rename_all(~ gsub("_", " ", .))
pcm = melt(pc, id = c("Sample"))
pcm$Sample <- factor(pcm$Sample,levels=unique(pcm$Sample))
mx = ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Sample, fill = variable, y = value)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 8, colour = "black", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, face= "bold"), 
     axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), legend.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold"), 
     legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", colour = "black"), 
     axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold")) + 
     scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + 
     labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Phylum") +
     geom_col() +
     facet_wrap(~species)
     mx
```

Any help here would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your pivoting hasn't worked out properly - you will see that if you look at `pcm`. You should only pivot columns 2:10. The modern way to do this would be with `pivot_longer`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pc <- structure(list(Sample = c("S047424", "S047423", "S047422", "S047420", 
"S047419", "S047418", "S047417", "S047404", "S047402", "S047400"
), Cyanobacteria = c(18.8176, 26.3215, 41.305, 98.2477, 19.6175, 
45.9008, 0.801603, 10.0267, 1.67364, 25.9087), Rhodophyta = c(10.2027, 
22.8883, 1.91199, 0, 0, 0, 8.01603, 58.2888, 70.9044, 27.959), 
Unknown_phylum = c(21.6216, 17.4932, 14.5372, 1.75232, 42.3893, 
0, 67.4349, 23.262, 11.2649, 31.8733), Chlorophyta = c(28.8514, 
22.8883, 39.5751, 0, 37.9932, 0, 3.00601, 2.31729, 0, 0), 
Bacillariophyta = c(0, 1.3624, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.2385, 2.94118, 
11.0074, 9.13327), Cercozoa = c(16.3851, 5.61308, 0.971168, 
0, 0, 54.0992, 1.50301, 3.16399, 0, 5.12582), Apicomplexa = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Unclassified = c(4.12162, 
3.43324, 1.69954, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.14966, 0), Streptophyta = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), species = c("Species_Name_1", 
"Species_Name_1", "Species_Name_1", "Species_Name_2", "Species_Name_2", 
"Species_Name_2", "Species_Name_2", "Species_Name_3", "Species_Name_3", 
"Species_Name_3")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

pc %>% 
  mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, unique(Sample)),
         species = gsub('_', ' ', species)) %>%
  rename_all(~gsub('_', ' ', .)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Sample, species)) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(color = 'black', size = 0.3) +
  facet_grid(~species, scales = 'free_x') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Spectral', direction = -1) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Phylum")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much but this doesn't seem to preserve the order of the samples as they appear in the input file and also doesn't remove the underscores in the SpeciesName (not present in the example I posted here though). Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew yes, you need to make them a factor with the order in which they appear. Put `pc %>% mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, unique(Sample)))` as the first line in the code above rather than just `pc %>%`

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew updated to demonstrate

Comment: Thanks again but the order of the legend isn't preserved either and I'm unable to get rid of the underscores in the SpeciesName; for example when there is Species_Name_1, it should appear as Species Name 1

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew there are no underscores in the species names in your example, but I will update to do this for you. The items in the legend also need to be made factor levels. I will show you this too.

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew Please see my update. The Species and samples are now in the order in which they appear in your data. I have included fully reproducible input data with underscores in the names and the code now removes these, as well as the underscores in the column names.

Comment: Thanks again for your time but now I'm confused how to load pc directly from a csv file. I have a large dataset and I dont want to be writing up structure(list(Sample and so on. Sorry for my silly & annoying questions; I'm a R beginner

Comment: In my original code, I had also indicated labs(x = "", y = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "Phylum") to give title to my legend. Is it possible to give a title to the legend in your code? No more queries, I promise

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew no, you don't need to write `structure(list...` and so on. _I_ have to do that to get the data because _I do not have your CSV file_. You can just use `read.csv` as normal to get `pc`, then the rest of the code should work for you. I will update with your labels.

Comment: @RodriguezJMathew see my update.

Comment: This is fantastic- thanks a zillion! Apologies for some of my silly queries and thanks once again for your saintly patience with me